# Rails storing string in session makes it lowercase, how to preserve string case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

In my Rails 5 application, I am saving a string in session, but when retrieving that string it is all changed to lower-case which is problematic in my use-case.

**How to save the string in session while maintaining its case?**

My usage is:
`session[:email] = "AbC@testemail.com"`

currently the retrieved value is `"abc@testemail.com"`

I need to retrieve `"AbC@testemail.com"`

Note:

I know emails are usually are case-insensitive but I need to maintain the string case if possible nonetheless